# Http Bad Request 400 for Asp.net Web Api in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my configuration and code .

```
public class DeployLogController : ApiController
    {
        // GET /api/DeployLog
        public List<DeployLogModel> Get(Guid deployDetailId, Guid? deployLogId)
        {

            DeployLogService service = DeployLogService.Instance;

            return service.GetNewestDeployLogs(deployDetailId, deployLogId).ToList();

        }

        // POST /api/DeployLog
        public void Post(DeployLogModel deployLogModel)
        {
            DeployLogService service = DeployLogService.Instance;
            service.SavaDeployLogByServer(deployLogModel);
        }

    }
```

and the code of Application_Start in Global.asax.cs is below.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();
            Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        }
```

Why did I got 400 Http Response message When I accessed the Url "http://localhost:8119/api/DeployLog". Seems the code

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
```

doesn't work.Did I miss something ? please help me . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Phil Haack's [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to determine if the correct route is being hit.

It looks like you're either hitting the wrong route, or your route does not have a controller method that corresponds with it (at first glance, it appears that your setup is expecting a controller method called GET, not DeployLog.

Comment: Sure? HTTP 400 tends to be generated by HTTP.SYS or IIS directly and is usually caused by a malformed HTTP request. If the routing was failing then you'd just get a HTTP 404. It's also possible he's using a HTTP verb that isn't supported. I think the OP should test his WebAPI client on another service, or test his WebAPI with a desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently - it was caused by different types of arguments put into the controller function. In my example in controller there had integer parameter but I tried string as an argument to web api query. That is why routing didn't work.